# Upgrade angular app to use @angular/fire 5.1.0

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire5

I'm am trying to upgrade my application to use @angular/fire instead of angularFire2 because its deprecated. The moment that I upgraded evrything i got this error message:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.d.ts(4,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
node_modules/@angular/fire/database/interfaces.d.ts(2,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,79): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
```

So I started searching the web for solutions. eventually I found an answer [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1387#issuecomment-352835953)

And it stated that i need to downgrade firebase back to version '4.8.0'. When I did that the error was gone but I got this new error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.d.ts(12,45): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase.auth' has no exported member 'IdTokenResult'.
node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,42): error TS2305: Module '"D:/School/App & Gui Dev/Project_Mariën_Seppe/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has no exported member 'functions'.
```

Versions:

- "@angular/fire": "^5.1.0",
- "firebase": "^4.12.1" (I tried from 4.8.0 to 5.5.7),
- "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",

If you need more information please don't hesitate to ask

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of that error using the following configuration

> "@angular/fire": "^5.1.0",
>   "firebase": "^5.5.9",
>   "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
>   "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
>   "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",

Hope that helps